# Excel VBA - Preserve source format when importing .txt

Tags: excel, vba

**Problem:**
When importing a *.txt*, my timestamp column is getting messed up. I'm losing millisecond and date information. I want to import *.txt* files without losing any information. See below:

Source Format
2021-10-12 10:18:48.258

Excel Format after Import
18:48.3

**What I've Tried:**
I've played around with Workbooks.OpenText and QueryTables.Add. I have the same problem with Workbooks.OpenText. The macro errors out and won't run when I attempt to use QueryTables.Add.

**Context/Code:**
VBA macro that opens and edits all *.txt* files found in a specific folder.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

ChDir "C:\Users\mjkut\Desktop\SmrtSkt\Sensor Data\EXCEL OUTPUT"

Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim Headers() As Variant

MyFolder = "C:\Users\mjkut\Desktop\SmrtSkt\Sensor Data\EXCEL QUEUE"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.txt")
Headers = Array("TIME", "a_X", "a_Y", "a_Z", "w_X", "w_Y", "w_Z", "ang_X", "ang_Y", "ang_Z")

Do While MyFile <> ""
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile, Format:=2
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("B:B,F:F,J:J,N:ZZ").EntireColumn.Delete
        .Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert
            For i = LBound(Headers()) To UBound(Headers())
                .Cells(1, 1 + i).Value = Headers(i)
            Next i
        .Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileFormat:=52
    MyFile = Dir
Loop

ChDir "C:\Users\mjkut\Documents"

End Sub
```

Comment: Side note: You can skip the entire `For i` loop and just write the entire `Headers` array to a range, probably using `Resize` to size the range appropriately.

Comment: Excel may be (un)-helpfully trying to convert that string into a Date/Time serial number, and applying a format to the result.   Check the underlying cell values and cell format to see if that's the case.

Comment: The example you give is ambiguous.  Is it 12 Oct or 10 Dec?  If Excel _is_ trying to convert it, the result may or may not align with your expectations

Comment: If Opening the txt file doesn't give you what you want,  then read it line by line, process it yourself to your needs,  then place and format the results on a sheet

Comment: In which column is the problematic time format? Since, it is not a standard time format, it should be imported as text. If the `Headers` array you use keeps all of them and the number of columns can be extracted from it, if you tell me/us which is the problematic column, I can show you a way of opening as you need. In fact, you should use `OpenText`...

Comment: Is the text file to be open Tab delimited?

Comment: @FaneDuru column A has the problematic time format. The text files are comma delimited. I changed the delimiter from tab to comma in the code example you posted and gave it a try. No luck. The first column still comes in as the problematic custom format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code using QueryTables works for me. Thank you everyone for acting as a sounding board.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

ChDir "C:\Users\mjkut\Desktop\SmrtSkt\Sensor Data\EXCEL OUTPUT"

Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim ConnStr As String
Dim SaveName As String
Dim Headers() As Variant

MyFolder = "C:\Users\mjkut\Desktop\SmrtSkt\Sensor Data\EXCEL QUEUE"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.txt")
Headers = Array("TIME", "a_X", "a_Y", "a_Z", "w_X", "w_Y", "w_Z", "ang_X", "ang_Y", "ang_Z")

Do While MyFile <> ""
    ConnStr = "TEXT;" & MyFolder & "\" & MyFile
    SaveName = Left(MyFile, Len(MyFile) - 4)
    Workbooks.Add
    Set Sheet = Worksheets(1)
    Set qt = Sheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=ConnStr, Destination:=Sheet.Cells(2, 1))
    With qt
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(xlTextFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat)
        .Refresh
    End With

    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("B:B,F:F,J:J,N:ZZ").EntireColumn.Delete
            For i = LBound(Headers()) To UBound(Headers())
                .Cells(1, 1 + i).Value = Headers(i)
            Next i
        .Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
    End With

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveName, FileFormat:=52
    MyFile = Dir

Loop

ChDir "C:\Users\mjkut\Documents"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next code. You should use `timeColumn` to choose the column to be open as text. The code uses 1, just for testing reason. Please set your necessary column number:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim MyFolder As String, MyFile As String, Headers()
 Dim timeColumn As Long, arrCols(), nrCols As Long, i As Long

 MyFolder = "C:\Users\mjkut\Desktop\SmrtSkt\Sensor Data\EXCEL QUEUE"
 MyFile = dir(MyFolder & "\*.txt")
 Headers = Array("TIME", "a_X", "a_Y", "a_Z", "w_X", "w_Y", "w_Z", "ang_X", "ang_Y", "ang_Z")
 nrCols = UBound(Headers): timeColumn = 1 'the problematic column, to be open as text
 ReDim arrCols(nrCols)

 Do While MyFile <> ""
    For i = 0 To nrCols 'build the array telling to Excel the necessary format for each file column
        If i = timeColumn - 1 Then
            arrCols(i) = Array(1, 2) 'open as text
        Else
            arrCols(i) = Array(1, 1) 'open as General
        End If
    Next
    Workbooks.OpenText fileName:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile, origin:=932, startRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        Tab:=True, FieldInfo:=arrCols()

    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("B:B,F:F,J:J,N:ZZ").EntireColumn.Delete
        .Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert
            For i = LBound(Headers()) To UBound(Headers())
                .cells(1, 1 + i).value = Headers(i)
            Next i
        .rows(1).Font.Bold = True
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
      ActiveWorkbook.Close True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'ActiveWorkbook.saveas FileFormat:=52 'if you prefer this way, you should delete the above way and uncomment this line
                                          'it, probably, must be closed after each iteration, to avoid Excel resources wasting
    MyFile = dir()
 Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: No joy. This code gives the same result.

Comment: @mjkutzman This cannot be possible, if you choose the correct `timeColumn`, I think. If not something confidential, can you share the file you try opening? At least, a dummy one, having only some rows with real data respecting the problematic pattern... You can send it on my personal mail account (from may profile, but announce me, please. Otherwise it will be consider Spam...), or a transfer site.

Comment: I was able to find a solution using QueryTables. Thank you for all your help, FaneDuru!